Can VSCode be used without the GUI?
I installed VSCode using snap. I see /snap/bin in my path, but when I run code nothing happens. I also never install GUIs with my OS if I can avoid it. Do I have to have a GUI to use the VSCode app in Ubuntu?

As more of a side remark: There are editors that are specifically meant to be used on the command line, like vim (though that one has a significant learning curve), Emacs, nano, .... Maybe one of those would be a better choice for your use case than VSCode.

VSCode's GUI provides a rich editing experience with features like syntax highlighting, code completion, debugging tools, and an integrated terminal.
VSCode also has a built-in command-line interface (CLI) that offers limited access to some of its features, but you can't directly edit code or visualize debugging information through the VSCode CLI.

Alternatively Neovim (sudo apt install neovim) is a fork of Vim focused on modern code and features, rather than running in legacy environments.
Advantages of Neovim:

Neovim emphasizes keyboard shortcuts for fast and precise editing.
Running in the terminal, Neovim is lightweight and consumes fewer resources compared to GUI-based editors.
Neovim allows extensive customization through plugins.
Many plugins integrate Neovim with popular developer tools like linters, version control systems and debuggers.

